# How to enable pdo_mysql in PHP 5?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have already uncommented the required extensions in php.ini, but still nothing changed. How to enable `pdo_mysql` in PHP 5?

Comment: Did you make sure you have modified the correct php.ini? There is mostly two, one for the CLI and one for the Apache. Also, did you restart Apache?

Comment: I wonder what people have against installing PHP with the official installers...

Comment: I have installed php from appserv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which distro? If it's redhat based, you can try `yum install php-pdo`